# Flink kafka connector and flink version

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[flink kafka connector doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#upgrading-to-the-latest-connector-version) says we should not upgrade Flink and Kafka Connector version at the same time.

But I can not use old version Kafka Connector with newer Flink.

I try to use flink-connector-kafka-010 1.10.2 with Flink 1.14 and get Exception:
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.common.state.OperatorStateStore.getSerializableListState(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/state/ListState;`

So can I just upgrade Flink and Kafka Connector version at same time and use offset in Kafka broker with same group id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first upgrade to a newer version of your Kafka connector on your existing Flink version, before upgrading to a newer version of Flink.

Comment: Is Flink kafka connector 1.14 compatiable with Flink 1.10 ? I found I can not call StreamExecutionEvironment#addSource(Flink 1.10) with KafakSource(Flink 1.14)

Comment: You should not mix and match Kafka connector versions and Flink versions. They have no compatibility guarantees.

Comment: I think I missunderstond "Kafka connector version". It actually means flink-connector-kafka-0.8_2.11，flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11... flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11 and flink-connector-kafka_2.11（universal Kafka connector）。If I am using flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11 on Flink version 1.10, and I want to upgrade to Flink 1.14，I should upgrade Kafka connector from flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11 to flink-connector-kafka_2.11, both on Flink 1.10. And after that I should upgrade to Flink 1.14.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct upgrade path. First upgrade to the universal Kafka connector while remaining on the same Flink version and after that's done, upgrade your Flink version.